# Linear algebra and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have $A$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix, $B$ is $p \times q$ matrix and $C$ is a $5 \times 4 $ and I want to find the value of $p$ and $q$, how do I go around it and also if I want the size of $ABC$ if $ABC$ is defined?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly.

Comment: What is $q$ in order to have $BC$ defined?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little mnemonic that should help you: if an $a\times b$ matrix is multiplied by a $c\times d$ matrix, and it makes sense, then $b=c$, and the resulting matrix becomes $a\times d$. In short:
$$
(a\times \underbrace{b)\cdot (c}_{\text{equal}}\times d)=a\times d
$$
(This is a mnemonic, and as such I feel justified in abusing the $=$ sign.) For more than two matrices, this chains together the obvious way. For instance:
$$
(a\times \underbrace{b)\cdot (c}_{\text{equal}}\times \underbrace{d)\cdot(e}_{\text{equal}}\times f)=a\times f
$$